# How do you set up foreground firebase notification listener on react native app?

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

i just started learning react-native and currently trying to make a "heads-up push notification" using firebase cloud messaging, the notifications is working when the app is in background, but i still don't know how to make it work on foreground, here's what i did so far :

```
import type {Notification} from 'react-native-firebase';
....
async componentDidMount(){
     firebase.notifications().android.createChannel(channel);
     this.notificationListener = firebase.notifications().onNotification((notification: Notification)=>{
        console.log("notification =>" + notification);
    });
}

componentWillMount(){
     this.notificationListener();
}
....
```

the `console.log` didn't even run, any help will be appreciated, thanks!